# Does anybody know how to reject commits with CRLF line endings on Bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

We want to keep the line endings of committed files to be consistent, permit only unix format, reject any commits which contain CRLF on the server side. But I do not know how to set up pre-receive hook on Bitbucket.

Comment: If you use an IDE you can set it to always contain unix line ending

Comment: @SeekingAlpha - Assume he is talking about people making public commits.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set up a pre-receive hook on BitBucket.  Hooks like this allow arbitrary code to execute on the server and simply aren't a viable option for a hosting service like this.  If you need custom hooks like this you need to host your own repository.

You could distribute a pre-commit hooks to contributors that they can install in their local repositories to reject commits containing this sort of line ending.

You could receive notifications of new commits via a *post-receive* hook, which BitBucket implements by calling out to a URL of your choice, but at this point the changes have already been committed to the repository.