# Seeking Advice on Syntax Validation for Bitbucket UI Commits

Tags: validation, user-interface, syntax, bitbucket, commit

.I've noticed a common issue in our workflow where minor changes made directly through the Bitbucket UI, such as modifying version numbers or release names, sometimes lead to pipeline failures due to missing syntax elements like braces or colons in the code.

Is there a way to implement syntax validation for Bitbucket UI commits? I'm looking for a solution that could help prevent these types of errors and streamline our development process.

Comment: Is there  a reason you want to encourage using the BitBucket portal for commits?

Comment: Yes in bitbucket datacanter there are few repositeries/code template already there just  changing names version on UI  and  while commiting  team missing  some braces colons indrntation   causing syntax error need to resolve this issue if there are any way to  validate ui commit please suggest

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does anybody know how to reject commits with CRLF line endings on Bitbucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273407/does-anybody-know-how-to-reject-commits-with-crlf-line-endings-on-bitbucket)